# Visual Studio SSRS - Count with a Group

Tags: reporting-services

Im trying to figure out an Expression in SSRS.

I have 1000s of account details in a DB.

What i want to do is create a table that gives a count of members in each state like :

```
State        Members

AK            234

AL           654

AR           643
```

How do i add a subgroup to this expression

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!Agent_External_ID.Value)
```

Right now it results in the same person being counted twice as the state is not grouped.

Comment: Why aren't you grouping on the state? Normally, I would create a table and group on the state with the State with the same counting expression that you have. Is there a reason you can't? You could count over the whole dataset `=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!Agent_External_ID.Value = 'AK', Fields!Agent_External_ID.Value, 0), "Dataset1")` but you'd have to hard code each state.

Comment: you need to create table group on state column and delete detail column from group section and set expression on cell Count(Fields!Agent_External_ID.Value).